# Scrape data using Beautifulsoup giving javascript:void(0)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I scrape the below HTML element to get the link in href as example here:
https://www.sunshinetinyhomes.com
I've tried the below codes and the issue is that the outcome is

```
javascript:void(0) or None
```

**My code:**

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for list in lists:
try:
    website = list.find('a', class_="mlr__item__cta")['href']
except:
    website=''
print(website)
```

I've tried also the below but it gives `None`

```
website = list.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://")})
```

**The website element HTML:**

```
<a href="/gourl/860d9e703fe038a35b2ee780cec2f548976d60aa?redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sunshinetinyhomes.com%2F" class="mlr__item__cta" rel="nofollow" title="Sunshine Tiny Homes Ltd - Business Website" data-analytics="{&quot;lk_listing_id&quot;:&quot;102447349&quot;,&quot;lk_non-ad-rollup&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;lk_page_num&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;lk_pos&quot;:&quot;in_listing&quot;,&quot;lk_directory_heading&quot;:[{&quot;086834&quot;:[{&quot;00066200&quot;:&quot;0&quot;}]}],&quot;lk_geo_tier&quot;:&quot;dir&quot;,&quot;lk_area&quot;:&quot;left_1&quot;,&quot;lk_relevancy&quot;:&quot;0&quot;,&quot;lk_name&quot;:&quot;website&quot;,&quot;lk_pos_num&quot;:&quot;11&quot;,&quot;lk_se_id&quot;:&quot;22ef4521-93ee-4c73-98f6-66b864a2f402_VGlueSBob21lcw_Q2FuYWRh&quot;,&quot;lk_ev&quot;:&quot;link&quot;,&quot;event_name&quot;:&quot;click - Website&quot;,&quot;lk_product&quot;:&quot;none&quot;}" target="_blank">
<span class="ypicon ypicon-web mlr__icon"></span><span class="serpMessage">Website</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Requests does not run Javascript. So, you cannot parse dynamic websites that need it without using other solutions like Selenium.

Comment: @OneCricketeer how can i solve the issue using selenium ?

Comment: First, are you sure there aren't multiple a tags with that class you're looking for? Secondly, we'd need to know what url you're using to tell you for sure, but Selenium would start an actual browser and run the Javascript... Then you can use BeautifulSoup to scrape the page after its rendered... Have you tried looking for examples?

Comment: better show URL for this page. Sometimes link can be hidden in other attribute or page may read interesting data from other url (as JSON) and you may get it without using Selenium and even without using BeautifulSoup

Comment: https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/Tiny+homes/Banda+ON : this is the link, i would like to scrape the website element